# Using strcmp and strcpy to sort province’s name in alphabetical order

Tags: c, sorting, c-strings, bubble-sort, function-definition

I am trying to implement `strcmp` and `strcpy` to re-arrange names in alphabetical order and there is an issue with my name array initialization.

The state array cannot be printed out on the console as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char sort(char [], char []);

int main() {
    char strStates[8] = {
        'Ontario', 'Quebec', 'Manitoba', 'Alberta',
        'British Colombia', 'Nova Scotia', '\0'
    };
    char strSorted[] = { '\0' };
    int x = 0;
    
    printf("\nThe list of states before being sorted in alphabetical order: %s", strStates);
    
    for (x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
        printf("\n%s", strStates);
    }
    
    sort(strStates[x], strSorted[x]);
    
    printf("\nThe list of states sorted alphabetically are: ");
    
    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        printf("\n%s", strStates[x]);
    }
    return 0;
}
    
char sort(char string1[], char string2[]) {
    int x, y = 0;
    
    for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        for (y = 1; y < 4; y++) {
            if (strcmp(string1[x], string1[y]) > 0) {
                strcpy(string2[y], string1[x]);
                strcpy(string1[x], string1[y]);
                strcpy(string[y], string2[y]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `'Ontario'` is one big mother of a character. Compiler probably warning you about this. Use double quotes.

Comment: You have declared an array of characters, when it's clear that you want an array of strings. There's no point in writing any more code until that is fixed. And if you don't understand the difference then you need to revise C types before going any further.

Comment: First of all, please don't do sorting yourself, use [the standard `qsort` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) instead.

Comment: `char strSorted[] = {'\0'};` is an array of exactly one character. There isn't much you can do with it.

Comment: And what does your text-books say about the difference between e.g `"a"` and `'a'`?

Comment: i dont know what the differences between "a" and 'a'

Comment: `char strStates[8]` hmmm .....

Comment: Side note. There are no States in Canada. Just territories and provinces.

Comment: @Woody OK you have to realise that in C a character (`char`) and a string are two different things. You really need to teach yourself about that difference before going any further.

Comment: @Woody if you do not know the difference between 'a' and "a" you should start from the book.

Comment: "[I] dont know what the differences between "a" and 'a' " If you don't have any C text-books, please try to get some. Borrow if you have to. That should be one of the very early bits in any decent book, tutorial or class. And it's an important part. Please don't skip any parts of the books, tutorials or classes.

Comment: `"a"` is a string with an implied `NULL` termination character.  In a `char` array would look like `char buf[] = {65, 0};` (or `{'a', 0}`).  An `'a'` is a single character, again with ASCII value `65`

Answer (score 0):

> *"...there is an issue with my name array initialization."*

There are other issues additional to the array initialization....

Note:  Single quotes in C depict a `char`.  Use double quotes.. Change:

```
'Ontario'
```

to

```
"Ontario"
```

everywhere.

Additionally the `\0` as the last element in the array is not necessary.  Each "..." string contains its own null terminator.
Array initialization:  arrays must be sized to contain the number of visible characters plus one additional byte for null terminator - for the longest string in the array.

Change

```
char strStates[8] = {'Ontario', ..., 'Nova Scotia','\0'};
```

To  (including 2D array notation)

```
char strStates[][18] = {"Ontario", ..., "Nova Scotia"};//British Columbia (17 + 1)
                  ^     ^       "       "           "
                 |longest string in collection
```

Or to this (avoids needing to know longest string in array.)

```
    char *strStates[] = {"Ontario", ..., "Nova Scotia"};
```

For the comparison question, the following is a minimal example of how you can do that, using `strcmp()` implementation of compare function in conjunction with the [qsort()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm) function:

```
int comp(const void* a, const void* b);

int main(void)
{
    char strStates[][18] = {"Ontario", "Quebec", "Manitoba", "Alberta","British Colombia","Nova Scotia"};

    qsort(strStates, size, 18, comp);

    return 0;
}

int comp(const void* a, const void* b) {
    const char* aa = (const char*)a;
    const char* bb = (const char*)b;
    return strcmp(aa, bb);
}
```

Comment: Easier array of pointers. there is no need to know the length of the longest string.

Comment: now i can print the array to console as expected but for the sorting part, i cannot get that right

Comment: so how can we implement the array of pointers to compare?

Comment: @Woody -  I would use [qsort()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm)

Comment: my teacher wants me to use strcmp

Answer (score 0):

You declared a character array of 8 characters

```
  char strStates[8] = {'Ontario', 'Quebec', 'Manitoba', 'Alberta','British                 Colombia','Nova Scotia','\0'};
```

and trying to initialize it with multibyte character constant as for example `'Ontario'` that have implementation defined values.

It seems you want to declare an array of string literals. In this case you should write for example

```
const char * strStates[] = 
{
    "Ontario", "Quebec", "Manitoba", "Alberta", "British Colombia","Nova  Scotia" 
};
```

Also it is a bad idea yo use magic numbers like 8

```
char strStates[8] = //...
```

or 7

```
for (x = 0; x < 7; x++)
```

or 4

```
for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
```

This makes the code unclear.

You can determine the size of the declared array as shown above the following way

```
const char * strStates[] = 
{
    "Ontario", "Quebec", "Manitoba", "Alberta", "British Colombia","Nova  Scotia" 
};

const size_t N = sizeof( strStates ) / sizeof( *strStates );
```

As a result for example the for loop that outputs elements of the array can look like

```
puts( "The list of states before being sorted in alphabetical order:" );     
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    puts( strStates[i] );
}
```

The array strSorted  declared like

```
char strSorted[] = {'\0'};
```

is not used in your program. Remove the declaration.

This call of the function `sort`

```
sort(strStates[x], strSorted[x]);
```

does not make sense. The argument expressions have the type `char` while the function expects arguments of the type `char *`.

The function sort can be declared the following way

```
void sort( const char *[], size_t );
```

and called like

```
sort( strStates, N );
```

The function definition that implements the bubble sort method can look like

```
void sort( const char * s[], size_t n ) 
{
    for ( size_t  sorted = 0; !( n < 2 ); n = sorted ) 
    {
        for ( size_t i = sorted = 1; i < n; i++ ) 
        {
            if ( strcmp( s[i], s[i-1] ) < 0 ) 
            {
                const char *tmp = s[i];
                s[i] = s[i-1];
                s[i-1] = tmp;

                sorted = i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void sort( const char * s[], size_t n )
{
    for (size_t sorted = 0; !( n < 2 ); n = sorted)
    {
        for (size_t i = sorted = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp( s[i], s[i - 1] ) < 0)
            {
                const char *tmp = s[i];
                s[i] = s[i - 1];
                s[i - 1] = tmp;

                sorted = i;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *strStates[] =
    {
        "Ontario", "Quebec", "Manitoba", "Alberta", "British Colombia","Nova  Scotia"
    };

    const size_t N = sizeof( strStates ) / sizeof( *strStates );

    puts( "The list of states before being sorted in alphabetical order:" );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        puts( strStates[i] );
    }

    sort( strStates, N );

    puts( "\nThe list of states sorted alphabetically are:" );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        puts( strStates[i] );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
The list of states before being sorted in alphabetical order:
Ontario
Quebec
Manitoba
Alberta
British Colombia
Nova  Scotia

The list of states sorted alphabetically are:
Alberta
British Colombia
Manitoba
Nova  Scotia
Ontario
Quebec
```